# Save and Debug at same time Flash CS3

Tags: flash, cs3

Is there a way where I can save and debug a file in flash cs3 with combo keystrokes??
I'm running cs3 on a windows computer and I usually do ctrl+s to save and then do ctrl+shift+enter to debug... and I was just wondering if I can combine these 2 actions with one combination of keystrokes.
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...

you can write a jsfl script for that and save it in the Commands folder in Flash/Configutation.

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().save();
```

is what you need to save the document. I encountered a bug in Flash CS3 though, and only

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().saveAndCompact();
```

seemed to work. This would be annoying to use all the time.

And there is no

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().debugMovie();
```

in the jsfl documenatation.

I'm affraid the answer is no. I hope someone will prove me wrong.